# Internal error launching WP Emulator 7.1 on Visual Studio 2012 Windows 8 with Windows Phone 8 SDK

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I got an "**Internal Error**"-"**Connection failed because of invalid command-line arguments.**" error when launching Windows Phone Emulator 7.1. I got the error from both my converted WP7.1 project and a fresh new WP7.1 project created with Windows Phone SDK 8.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Professional on Windows 8 through Parallels Desktop on my MacBook Pro.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: take a look at [this post](http://blog.toddysm.com/2012/11/windows-phone-8-development-on-mac-all-the-gotchas.html) - not promising though I have not tried

Comment: I had this issue and did a repair on VS2012 and then all was well.

Comment: @ShawnKendrot, I tried repair and it didn't work for me.

Comment: @JimO'Neil, it talked about WP8 emulator, not WP7.1 emulator. But thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error when I had both SDKs installed and both VS2010 & 2012 open at the same time. I was able to resolve it by only using the 2012 version.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is you Windows Phone 8 emulator working fine? If not, that could be an issue with Hyper V running in a VM environment.

Comment: No, WP8 emulator doesn't work because of lack of Hyper-V. I gave up on that. But I can't even use WP7.1 emulator.

Comment: Yes, I've had an issue getting WP7.5 emulator to work as well. The WP8 emulator works fine, but the WP7.5 emulator keeps saying "loading..." for me and nothing else happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the 7.1 emulator from within a virtual machine.

Comment: Can you tell me why? I can't seem to find any MSDN article talking about this. thanks.